# MVC Authorization - Store Action & Roles authorization inside database

Tags: security, model-view-controller, roles, provider

I am still quite new to MVC, and still trying to wrap my head around the security of MVC.

At the moment, it seems that each 'Action' in controller is restricted by the Roles/Users values listed in the 'Authorize' attribute if present. In a way, this is hardcoded, and will require code change each time the roles link to each controller 'Action' is changed.

I am wondering, is there a way I can use a database to store these values, and retrieve it dynamically instead?

Eg of tables in DB :
- Table to store Action/Role links
- Table to store all Actions
- Table to store all Roles
- Table to store Role/User links
- Table to store all Users

This way, I need not hardcode the required roles for each 'Action' with an 'Authorize' attribute. A change in DB will suffice.

Is the above possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that, but not without writing some custom code.

Take a look at the [Thinktecture Resource/Action based authorization](http://leastprivilege.com/2014/06/24/resourceaction-based-authorization-for-owin-and-mvc-and-web-api/). It will allow you to plug in your own AuthorizationManager class.